# Android - Location Manager - weird crashing issue

Tags: android, locationmanager

I'm kinda lost here.. Basically I need to get the user's general location in the fastest, lightest, way possible. This is the code I have

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);                 
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(false);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
Log.d(TAG,"Lat - " + (location.getLatitude()) + " long - " + (location.getLongitude()));
```

Yesterday it worked pefectly for me but today I get a Null Pointer error when `Log.d` tries to access `location`. I sent the app to two friends and it ran fine on their phones. Is there something I can change to make the code more robust? What might have caused the crashes on my phone?

Edit - I got a gps lock in Maps and went back to my app but it still crashes..

Comment: Null checks around the Log statement.

Comment: May you have add a locationlistener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

This will not always return a location. Infact many a times it gives `NULL`.

You must always check if location is `NULL`.

```
if(location != null){
      Log.d(TAG,"Lat - " + (location.getLatitude()) + " long - " + (location.getLongitude()));
}
```

Reason for null location might be, the `provider's` **LastKnownLocation** has expired(old timestamp).

Comment: i made sure to get a gps lock in maps and then go back, but the app still crashes..    how do i force a new location update? thank

Comment: Since you have asked for `criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);` the best provider will be **NETWORK_PROVIDER**. So, I think the **GPS** lock doesn't matter.

Comment: i just experimented with different accuracy levels. it still crashes

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the reference here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String); you will see that `getLastKnownLocation` :

> Returns the last known location for the provider, or null

So yeah your `location` object can be null sometimes. I have no idea why it happens but it does. I have a feeling it happens more often after long period of times where the device hasn't used location services.

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria most likely result in Network location, when Wifi is not available then cell tower is used and thus may incured cost if your data used is over the limit. Thus for Network the cost is true. Thus if you change

```
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
```

you will be OK.

Comment: Instead of criteria, just use locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) and see if it still crashes. If it is then there is no last known Network location.

Comment: what do you mean by GPS lock? do you mean a fix?

Comment: did that and it crashed. switched to gps and it worked... i think there is a problem in my phone's network location..    yes. gps fix

Comment: this seems to work now - 'criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_LOW);'
        'criteria.setCostAllowed(true);'
        'provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);'
        'Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);'

Comment: Your original criteria result in what is call a passive Provider. That is if some app get a fix then you get a ride on it. You just get a fix from map now passive provider has last known location.

Answer (score 0):

Your location is null so you can get error

```
if(location != null){
      Log.d(TAG,"Lat - " + (location.getLatitude()) + " long - " + (location.getLongitude()));
}
```

[Location Demo](http://niravranpara.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-get-current-gps-location.html)